# How to read data from a table and assign them to variables of correct underlying data type generically in.NET

Tags: .net, generics, types

I want to read data from a table and assign them to variables of correct underlying data type generically. That is, once the logic is implemented, it can be used for any table containing any data type of column, in .NET

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should just use an ORM, like Linq to SQL or Entities Framework, or NHibernate (etc.).  They do exactly that; map database tables to .NET classes, doing all of the proper type conversions.

Comment: it is not used in this scenario.